# Como faço para adicionar o "mesmo" objeto numa list e ainda mudar uma propriedade?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, entity-framework, lista, jpa

Tenho que enviar uma List de entitys para um método que fará o insert dessas entitys no banco. Essa entidade representa uma inscrição de um paciente que entrará em algumas filas de espera de especialidades diferentes. Então a inscrição do paciente João na fila de ortopedia e de cardiologia. O meu registro no banco é por especialidade, então o joão teria dois registros no banco, um para cada especialidade. O problema é que eu não estou conseguindo montar essa List com as inscrições por especialidade. Apenas o primeiro item da List fica na List, os demais ficam como referência ao objeto isncrição.

```
public Response cadastrarEmMultiplasEspecialidades(
            @Valid InscricaoEsperaMultiplasEspecialidadesDTO inscricaoEsperaDTO) throws URISyntaxException {

        List<InscricaoEspera> inscricoes = new ArrayList<InscricaoEspera>();


        List<Especialidade> especialidades = inscricaoEsperaDTO.getEspecialidades();


        for (Especialidade especialidade : especialidades) {
            inscricaoEspera = inscricaoEsperaDTO.getInscricaoEspera();
            inscricaoEspera.setEspecialidade(especialidade);
            int result = inscricaoEsperaService.verificaPacienteNaListaEspera(inscricaoEspera).size();

            if (result == 0) {
                 InscricaoEspera insc = new InscricaoEspera();
                 insc = inscricaoEspera;
                inscricoes.add(insc);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Paciente já cadastrado! ");
                Response.status(Response.Status.CONFLICT).build();
            }
        }

        if (!inscricoes.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("entrou");
            List<InscricaoEspera> inscricaoEsperaPersistido = inscricaoEsperaService.inserir(inscricoes);

            return Response.created(new URI("/inscricaoEspera/" + inscricoes)).entity(inscricaoEsperaPersistido)
                    .build();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Pau! ");
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_ACCEPTABLE).build();
        }
    }
```

**InscricaoEsperaMultiplasEspecialidadesDTO:** esse *DTO* serve para que eu pegue uma lista de especialidades no front. Então ele é basicamente uma inscrição e uma list de especialidades.

**InscricaoEspera:** essa é a *entity* que fica salva no banco. Suas propriedades são o paciente, a especialidade, prioridade e data de cadastro.

**List inscricoes:** essa é a lista que passo para o método inscricaoEsperaService.inserir(inscricoes) que executa a inserção no banco.

Ao debugar, a lista *inscricoes* adiciona as inscrições, só que ao inspecionar o item da List fica como uma referência ao objeto `inscricaoEspera`, então ele só fica com a última especialidade.

Eu já sei que se eu fizer um new como o construtor parametrizado dentro do for e atribuir as propriedades do inscricaoEsperaDTO eu consigo evitar esse comportamento, mas me parece uma má pratica.

Resumidamente quero saber como evitar esse comportamento corretamente? Existe algum padrão para isso, principalmente se tratando de entitys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu já tive esse problema de referências, se não quiser ficar dando New Object no método add da List, você fazer sua classe InscricaoEspera  implementar a interface `Cloneable` e depois usar o metodo clone() para retornar uma cópia dos valores.

**OU**  vc pode criar um construtor que faz a cópia dos dados,  e usar ele para instanciar antes de adicionar na List;

fiz um exemplo veja se te atende:

Definir a classe implementando Cloneable

```
public class Person implements Cloneable{
  private Integer age;
  private String name;
  private Address address;

  public Person(Integer age, String name) {
    this.age  = age;
    this.name = name;
  }

  public Person() {
  }

 //CONSTRUTOR p/ CÓPIAS 
 public Person(Person original) {
   this.age = original.age;
   this.name = new String(original.name);
   this.address = new Address(original.address);
  }

  public Person clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return (Person) super.clone();
  }

}

public class Address {
    private String street;

    public Address(String st) {
      this.street = st;
    }
    public Address(Address address) {
      this.street = address.getStreet();
    }

}
```

**Como usar:**

```
 private static void testeList() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
          Person pessoa1 = new Person(32, "Cleber");
          List<Person> lst = new ArrayList<Person>();
          for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
            pessoa1.setAddress(new Address("rua "+i));
          //USANDO O CONSTRUTOR DE COPIAS
          //  Person pessoa2 = new Person(pessoa1);

            //USANDO CLONE()
            Person pessoa2 =  pessoa1.clone();
            lst.add(pessoa2);
          }
          lst.forEach( p-> System.out.println(p.getAddress().getStreet()));
          System.out.println(lst.size());
    }
```

Comment: muito melhor do que ficar dando new